# How to determine the marginal pdf, the posterior?

Tags: bayesian, self-study, normal-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution

How to get the marginal pdf of $p(y)$? Do you just integrate out $p({\sigma}^{2})$?

Say, the following joint distribution for $y \in {{R}^{d}}$ and ${{\sigma }^{2}}\in {{R}^{d}}$
IG: means inverse Gamma
$${{\sigma }^{2}}\sim IG(\alpha ,\beta )\propto {{({{\sigma }^{2}})}^{-(\alpha +1)}}{{e}^{-\beta /{{\sigma }^{2}}}}$$

$$y|{{\sigma }^{2}}\sim N(\mu ,{{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )$$

where $a\in R$, $b\in R$,$\mu \in {{R}^{d}}$,$\Sigma \in {{R}^{d\times d}}$ are known parameters.

I know that 
$$p(y|\mu,\Sigma)\propto \frac{1}{{{\left| {{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma  \right|}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}\exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{\left( {{y}_{i}}-\mu  \right)}^{T}}{{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}({{y}_{i}}-\mu )} \right]$$
$$\propto \frac{1}{{{\left| {{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma  \right|}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}\exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{\left( {{y}_{i}}-\bar{y} \right)}^{T}}{{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}({{y}_{i}}-\bar{y})-\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu )} \right]$$
$$\propto \frac{1}{{{\left| {{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma  \right|}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}\exp \left[ -\frac{n-1}{2}tr\left( {{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}S \right)-\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu ) \right]$$

what I have done is using

$$p{({\sigma}^{2})}{\times}p(y|{{\sigma }^{2}})$$

which gives me,
$$\propto {{\left( {{\sigma }^{2}} \right)}^{-(\alpha +1)}}{{e}^{-\beta /{{\sigma }^{2}}}}\times \frac{1}{{{\left| {{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma  \right|}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}\exp \left[ -\frac{n-1}{2}tr\left( {{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}S \right)-\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{({{\sigma }^{2}}\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu ) \right]$$

This doesn't look like anything to me, am I even on the right track?!  Anyways, if any experts knows, please point me out, thanks sooo much!

Comment: The answer is no!

Comment: More seriously, your last line is completely correct. So you are on the right track: remember that only $\sigma^2$ varies in this expression and that you can factorise most of the term in the exponential in $\sigma^2$. Then you should see a standard distribution in $\sigma^2$.

Comment: So, I think I will integrate the joint density(my last line) w.r.t. $\sigma^{2}$, then I get p(y).  Is that also what you are saying?  But I am not too sure about integration matrix.  I don't get what you mean by "factorise them".  Something like complete the square?

Comment: @Xi'an, I am reading Bayesian Core, in chapter 3.2.1 page 54, you had a similar example, how did you arrive to the results.  I am having trouble integrating out the $\sigma^{2}$.  It is attached to the matrix $\Sigma$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you get as your bottom line is of the form
$$
(\sigma^2) ^{-\alpha-1-nd/2}\exp\{-A\sigma^{-2}\}
$$
so the posterior distribution in $\sigma^{-2}$ is an inverse gamma distribution. (Note that 
$$
\text{tr}((\sigma^2\Sigma)^{-1}S)=\sigma^{-2}\text{tr}(\Sigma^{-1}S)\,.)
$$ 
From this property, you can derive the normalising constant.

Comment: Does this look right? $p(y)=\frac{1}{{{\left| \Sigma  \right|}^{n/2}}}\frac{\Gamma (a+n/2)}{{{\left( b+\frac{n-1}{2}tr\left( {{\Sigma }^{-1}}S \right)+\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{(\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu ) \right)}^{a+n/2}}}$

Comment: this is not any distribution I could recognize, more like a normalising constant with y bar in it.

Comment: Note that you can write the denominator as $\beta+(y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu)$.  note that the degrees of freedom is equal to double the power of this term minus the dimension of $y$ which gives us $v=2\alpha+n-d$.  thus we can write posterior as $$p(y)\propto\left[1+\frac{1}{v}(y-\mu)\left(\frac{\beta}{v}\Sigma\right)^{-1}(y-\mu)\right]^{-\frac{v+d}{2}}$$  this is the kernel of a student t distribution.

Comment: Yes, this is a Student's $t$ density.

Comment: Apologies the above is a bit wrong.  The exponent should be $\frac{v+nd}{2}$ and $v=2\alpha+n-nd$.  we should also have a block diagonal matrix with $n$ blocks equal to $\Sigma$ instead of just $\Sigma$.  also the term $(y-\mu)$ should be replaced by the $1\times nd$ row vector $\left[(y_1-\mu)^T,(y_2-\mu)^T,\dots,(y_n-\mu)^T\right]$.

Comment: That's an interesting mistake in that, indeed the vector $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ is Student but not the marginals.

Comment: @xian you made the same mistake i did.  The exponent for $\sigma^2$ should be$-(\alpha+1+\frac{nd}{2})$ as $|\sigma^2\Sigma|=\sigma^{2d}|\Sigma|$.  this means the degrees of freedom is simply $2\alpha$.

Comment: @probabilityislogic: right, I did!

Comment: @probabilityislogic and Xi'An, thanks for the help, the problem wasn't that bad, I think the trick was separating ${\sigma}^{2}$ from the matrix, integrating it, and then recognizing Student's t.  Anyways, thanks, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the normalising constant for a IG variable is

$$\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}$$

This is equal to the reciprical of the integral over $\sigma^{2}$ of the kernel of the pdf.  hence we have

$$\int_0^{\infty}(\sigma^{2})^{-(a+1)}\exp\left(-\frac{b}{\sigma^2}\right)d\sigma^2=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a}$$

Your integral is of this form for certain choice of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @user1061210 - the inverse gamma distribution is undefined for $\sigma^2\leq 0$.  The integral is then infinite for negative range.  You cannot have negative range for this parameter, as it is a normal distribution variance.  Similarly $\Sigma$ must be positive semi-definite (i.e. $x^T\Sigmax\geq 0$ for any vector $x$) for your distribution for $p(y|\sigma^2)$ to be valid

Comment: Does this look good? continued from my last line

$$={{\left( {{\sigma }^{2}} \right)}^{-(\alpha +1)-n/2}}\frac{1}{{{\left| \Sigma  \right|}^{n/2}}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{{{\sigma }^{2}}}\left[ b-\frac{n-1}{2}tr\left( {{\Sigma }^{-1}}S \right)-\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{(\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu ) \right] \right\}$$

Comment: integrate out ${sigma}^{2}$
$$=\frac{1}{{{\left| \Sigma  \right|}^{n/2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{\left( {{\sigma }^{2}} \right)}^{-(a+1+n/2)}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{{{\sigma }^{2}}}\left[ b+\frac{n-1}{2}tr\left( {{\Sigma }^{-1}}S \right)+\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{(\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu ) \right] \right\}}d{{\sigma }^{2}}$$

Comment: $p(y)=\frac{1}{{{\left| \Sigma  \right|}^{n/2}}}\frac{\Gamma (a+n/2)}{{{\left( b+\frac{n-1}{2}tr\left( {{\Sigma }^{-1}}S \right)+\frac{n}{2}{{(\bar{y}-\mu )}^{T}}{{(\Sigma )}^{-1}}(\bar{y}-\mu ) \right)}^{a+n/2}}}$

Comment: Yep you got it.  Note that this is called a multivariate student distribution.  It is not properly normalised though.  So you should replace $=$ with $\propto$

Comment: got it, isn't this suppose to follow some distribution?  We have IG and normal as prior and likelihood, respectively.  From experience, the posterior should fall into either one or a hybrid of both.